# Interaction between UserDetails, AuditorAware and JPA

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have probably made my life more complicated than necessary by opting for the following class hierarchy in my Spring Roo / Hibernate - JPA / Spring MVC / Spring Security application:

DomainBase (audit fields - references AbstractUsers for lastUpdatedBy and createdBy fields, so circular dependency...(!))

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@CreatedBy
private AbstractUser createdBy;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@LastModifiedBy
private AbstractUser lastModifiedBy;
```

^

|

AbstractUser ( contains general user information like names and a string user id)

```
@NotNull
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Immutable
private Set<UserRole> roles;
```

^

|

Operator, Consumer, Client (concrete users), System User

Other domain classes derive from DomainBase.

I use the following implementation of an Auditor:

```
public class SpringSecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<AbstractUser> {

    public AbstractUser getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();

        return ((AbstractUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

My implementation of `UserDetailsService` contains this:

```
userDetails = operatorRepository.findByUsername(username);

if (userDetails != null) {
    // overcome lazy load
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = userDetails
            .getAuthorities();
    roles.size();
    return userDetails;
}
```

The relationship between JPA Transaction and the Hibernate/JPA Session is still, unfortunately, unclear in my mind despite trying to consume the documentation and google around.  At the point the AuthenticationManager interrogates my UserDetailsService, clearly there is a live session and the user entity returned is associated with the persistence session (live) and the roles are read and used to determine later authorization outcomes.  At some later point in time, when the user makes a request that involves calling a `@Transactional` service method that causes a change to or creates a new entity, the `AuditorAware<>` listener fires and assigns the reference stored in the `SecurityContext` to this object and is subsequently persisted.

I know it is bad form to ask more than one question but they are all interrelated to this particular arrangement.

1)  Would it be better practice to make a deep copy of the user object to store in the `SecurityContext`, if so then what is a reasonable strategy for obtaining the 'live' entity when the Auditor is fired (except querying the repository each and every time)?

2)  I'm not really interested in persisting the user entities when dealing with domain objects in general, and tried setting `cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH` but of course I met with the user objects being transient in the context of the hibernate session.  I thought about simply storing the user Id in the `DomainBase` but then I lose the nice ability to lazily fetch user details if required.  Is there a 'best-practice' I could be following here?

A comment:  I seem to be running into trouble quite often with respect to the user roles collections of the same user attempting to be associated with two sessions at once (I have background scheduled jobs and I suspect my over zealous logging via `extends CustomizableTraceInterceptor` might have a lot to do with it).

Any guidance appreciated...

Comment: Any pattern or examples of patterns for UserDetails, Auditing and Spring Security?